# JQUERY CYCLE Plugin - Problems with 'Timeout' feature

Tags: jquery, timeout, cycle

I want to display three images 1second after one another using jQuery carousel. I don't have this using different timeout values for each image however once the images have animated for the third time each different slide starts doing it's own thing! By this I mean that the timings are becoming incoherent with one another. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Or is this the right way to use jQuery cycle?

Any help would be mostly appreciated

Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slide1').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            timeout:4000
        });

        $('#slide2').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            timeout:4200
        });

        $('#slide3').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            timeout:4400
        });

    });


</script>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who stumbles across this post. The answer is about using 'delay' rather than timeout.

So code would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#slide1').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout:4000,
        delay:0
    });

    $('#slide2').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout:4000,
        delay:200
    });

    $('#slide3').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout:4000,
        delay:400
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: By way of clarification, the `timeout` parameter is used for specifying the length of time that a slide transition should take.